# How do I target the nth-child() of a slotted element when a web component has multiple different named slots?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

I am trying to target the 2nd slotted element of a specific slot with `slot[name=foo]::slotted(:nth-child(2)){` but I am not getting what I expect. The 1st foo slot is green, but the second should be green.

I have a default slot, named slot of foo, and named slot of bar in a web component and want to target the 2nd slotted foo element.

None of these selectors in the template work as expected:

```
  slot[name=foo]::slotted(:nth-child(2)){
    outline: 2px solid green;
  }
  
  ::slotted(slot[name=foo]:nth-child(2)){
    outline: 2px solid green;
  }
  
  ::slotted(slot[name="foo"]:nth-child(2)){
    outline: 2px solid green;
  }
```

See my jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/donohueseth/msxojtac/14

How do I target the nth-child() of a slotted element when a web component has multiple different named slots?

Comment: slot[name=foo]::slotted(:nth-child(3)) should do it based on the jsfiddle.

Comment: The persons who closed your question know CSS, but not shadowDOM and :slotted. Delete your question (I can't re-open it) and ask again with title: **how to target shadowDOM slots with slotted pseudoselector** And maybe not add the CSS tag.. keeps the sharks from biting

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-child(numberHere)` gives you the `nth-child` that ***is*** the selector to the left of `:`. Meaning ***any*** child that is the second one and is `[slot=foo]`, in your case. You want the `:nth-of-type(numberHere)`, which gives you the `nth-of-type` to the left of `:`.

```
::slotted([slot=foo]:nth-of-type(2)){
  outline: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: No, this applies the CSS for the ``"second type IF it is A foo"``,**not** ``"the second type IN the foo slot"``. nth-child and nth-of-type work on **elements** not on classes or attribute selectors, and here shadowDOM is involved; so everything ::slotted applies to lightDOM, not the SLOTs

Comment: Ok but the answer is in the correct direction as I am expecting the selector to find the 2nd slot of foo, but really it is finding the 2nd slot, and IF it is foo then it applies the styles.